# what is MethodInvokingFactoryBean in spring IOC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ioc

I am new to the spring , and while going through this topic , I was unable to understand what is MethodInvokingFactoryBean 's exact use and when to use it ?
can someone please help me here

Comment: [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) This doc explains its usage

Answer (score 0):

MethodInvokingFactoryBean is used for invoking method of a class. It runs the method and gives you the result that u can get using the id of the bean that invoked it.